# Deriving Frobenius number for two denominations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

<s>I would like to know if the following question has an intelligent solution:</s>

Determine the largest bet that cannot be made using chips of $7$ and $9$ dollars.

After not being able to solve it I found a solution online which writes out all combinations of $7$ and $9$ up to $90$ and then notes that we can produce all numbers after $47$ so the largest bet is $47$.

Then after asking this question here on the site I got pointed to the formula for the Frobenius number  on Wikipedia: $g(a,b) = ab - a- b$. But Wikipedia does not explain this formula.

> How to derive this formula? Why is the Frobenius number for two coins
>   $ab - a - b$ where $a,b$ are the denominations of the coins?

Comment: This is known as the ''coin problem'' in some circles. Wikipedia has a helpful article; see specifically the case $n = 2$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_2. The following article might also be helpful: http://cosmos.ucdavis.edu/archives/2009/cluster6/Chen_Kevin.pdf

Comment: Hint: $47=7\cdot9-7-9.$ This works for any pair of relatively prime numbers.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you, your comment helped me greatly.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I wish Wikipedia would explain why $g(a_1,a_2) =a_1a_2 - a_1 - a_2$.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to imagine $a<b$. As ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$ the $a$ numbers
$$r_j:=j\>b\quad(0\leq j\leq a-1)$$
represent the $a$ different remainders modulo $a$. At the same time $r_j$ is the smallest representable number having that remainder modulo $a$: You need at least $j$ summands $b$ to produce that remainder. It follows that all numbers  $r_j+k\>a$ $(k\geq 0)$ are representable, but $r_j-a$, $\>r_j-2a$, $\>\ldots\>$, are not. Since $r_{a-1}$ is the largest of the $r_j$ the largest non-representable number $g(a,b)$ is given by $$g(a,b)=r_{a-1}-a=ab-a-b\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

A very nice explanation is given at [Cut the knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Sylvester2.shtml).

You want the number for $p, q$ with $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ (otherwise it makes no sense). Consider the $q$ sequences:

$\begin{align}
   &0 + 0, 0 + q, 0 + 2 q, \dotsc \\
   &p + 0, p + q, p + 2 q, \dotsc \\
   &\vdots \\
   &(q - 1) p + 0, (q - 1) p + q, \dotsc
\end{align}$

They have no elements in common. Now take the series:

$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{r p + k q}
    &= z^{r p} \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{k q} \\
    &= \frac{z^{r p}}{1 - z^q}
\end{align}$

Add them all up:

$\begin{align}
   \sum_{0 \le r \le q - 1} \frac{z^{r p}}{1 - z^q}
     &= \frac{1}{1 - z^q} \sum_{0 \le r \le q - 1} z^{r p} \\
     &= \frac{1}{1 - z^q} \frac{1 - z^{q p}}{1 - z^p} \\
     &= \frac{1 - z^{p q}}{(1 - z^p) (1 - z^q)}
\end{align}$

The coefficients of this are all 0 (the number isn't representable) or 1 (the number is representable). We get the series with 1 for non-representable ones by:

$\begin{align}
   \frac{1}{1 - z} - \frac{1 - z^{p q}}{(1 - z^p) (1 - z^q)}
     &= \frac{(1 - z^p) (1 - z^q) - (1 - z) (1 - z^{p q})}
             {(1 - z) (1 - z^p) (1 - z^q)}
\end{align}$

This is a *polynomial* (it is easy to see that large enough numbers are all representable). Its degree is the last non-representable number, and that is just the degree of the numerator less the degree of the denominator:

$\begin{align}
   (1 + p q) - (p + q + 1)
     = p q - p - q
\end{align}$

As the coefficients are all 1, we can also get the number of non-representable ones as:

$\begin{align}
   \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{(1 - z^p) (1 - z^q) - (1 - z) (1 - z^{p q})}
                       {(1 - z) (1 - z^p) (1 - z^q)}
\end{align}$

Applying l'Hôpital thrice gives:

$\begin{align}
   \frac{−3 p q (p q − p − q + 1)}{- 6 p q}
     = \frac{p q - p - q + 1}{2}
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you very much. This turns out to be longer than I expected. I will take some time to read your answer.

Comment: @astudent hope this helps, it id the clearest proof I've seen. And thanking around here is by up voting and/or accepting answers. Hope this hels